# Como regresar al inicio de un switch en c++

Tags: c++, switch

estoy haciendo un switch con diferentes opciones, pero siempre que le doy a una opcion y cumple su proposito el programa se acaba, y lo que deseo es que despues de que se acabe la opcion me regrese al principio del switch

```
int main() {
    int menu = 0;


    cout<<"TABLA PERIODICA\n";
    cout<<"MENU\n";
    cout<<" 1:Ver todos los Elementos 2: integrantes 3: salir";
    cin>>menu;

    switch(menu){

        case 1:

            break;

        case 2:
            cout<<"Integrantes del Equipo\n";
            cout<<"Jhair Alejandro Cruz Palacios 223244\n";
            break;

        case 3:
            cout<<"Adios";
            break;

        default:
            cout<<"Opcion no reconocida";
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no pones el el switch dentro de un while entonces? Así se repetirá.

Comment: cambia al final el return 0, por return main();

Comment: @Yussef no se puede llamar a `main` dentro de `main`, está prohibido por el propio estándar del lenguaje y su efecto es imprevisible.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Yo lo probé y funcionó

Comment: @Yussef también puedes clavar clavos a cabezazos y funciona, lo cuál no significa que sea la manera correcta de clavar clavos.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Busqué información al respecto y no encontré nada que respaldara lo que dices

Comment: @Yussef [Estándar de C++](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2022/n4910.pdf) (Versión C++23) §6.9.3.1.3 main function «**The function `main` shall not be used within a program**».

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Vale gracias!! Me había quedado con la duda

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres repetir un cacho de código, ponlo en un bucle:

```
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout
        << "TABLA PERIODICA\n"
           "MENU\n"
           " 1:Ver todos los Elementos 2: integrantes 3: salir";

    do // <--- Bucle
    {
        int menu = 0;
        cin >> menu;

        switch(menu)
        {
        case 1:
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "Integrantes del Equipo\n"
                    "Jhair Alejandro Cruz Palacios 223244\n";
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "Adios";
            return 0; // <--- Rompemos el bucle saliendo

        default:
            cout << "Opcion no reconocida";
            break;
        }
    } while(true); // El bucle es infinito, sólo sale en el case 3.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: se lo agradezco mucho, logro resolver mi duda.